# Using LEFT JOIN to only selection one joined row

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to LEFT JOIN two tables, to get a list of all rows from TABLE_1 and ONE related row from TABLE_2. I have tried LEFT JOIN and GROUP BY c_id, however I wan't the related row from TABLE_2 to be sorted by isHeadOffice DESC.

Here are some sample tables

```
TABLE 1
c_id    Name
----------------
1       USA
2       Canada
3       England
4       France
5       Spain

TABLE2
o_id    c_id    Office              isHeadOffice
------------------------------------------------
1       1       New York            1
2       1       Washington          0
3       1       Boston              0
4       2       Toronto             0
5       3       London              0       
6       3       Manchester          1
7       4       Paris               1
8       4       Lyon                0
```

So what I am trying to get from this would be something like:

```
RESULTS
c_id    Name        Office
----------------------------
1       USA         New York
2       Canada      Toronto
3       England     Manchester
4       France      Paris
5       Spain       NULL
```

I'm using PHP & MySQL. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table1 t1
LEFT JOIN
        table2
ON      o.id = 
        (
        SELECT  o_id
        FROM    table2 t2
        WHERE   t2.c_id = t1.c_id
        ORDER BY
                t2.c_id DESC, t2.isHeadOffice DESC, t2.o_id DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

Create an index on `table2 (c_id, isHeadOffice, o_id)` for this to work fast.

The `ORDER BY` clause in the subquery may seem redundant but it is required for `MySQL` to pick the right index.

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
SELECT c_id, name, 
(SELECT t2.office 
 FROM table2 t2 
 WHERE t2.c_id = t1.c_id AND t2.isHeadOffice = 1
 LIMIT 1) office
FROM table1 t1
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Comment: I believe you need an "Order By isHeadOffice Desc" clause in the subquery.

Comment: well, the source table here is table1 which does not have that field; ffrom table2 I just get the office field

Comment: I've just added the ORDER BY 3 DESC

Comment: This would generally be the poorest performing way to do this. I never consider using a subquery when a join will do.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that your isHeadOffice is a bit field and you will only have one head office per country.

```
SELECT
    Table1.c_id,
    Table1.Name,
    Table2.Office
FROM
    Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Table2
ON
    Table1.c_id = Table2.c_id
AND
    Table2.isHeadOffice = 1
```